# History data from IE

Tags: internet-explorer

Where does Internet Explorer store the history data, i.e. the list of URL that have been visited? I am using Windows XP SP3 and IE7. Basically I would like to read the list of URL and make some statistics on how often what pages are visited.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer seems to keep its history in hidden directories under C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\History\History.IE5.  Note that some directories in this path are also marked hidden or system.  The history's format is opaque, but [there's code at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/IECache.aspx) that can decode the contents.  You can also find a list of typed URLs under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs.

An easier alternative might be to setup an HTTP proxy between the IE and the internet, and then examine the proxy's log.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is CoCreate(CLSID_CUrlHistory, IID_IUrlHistoryStg) and call [IUrlHistoryStg::EnumUrls()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767720(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's stored in the registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs